# Why does Polymer require Polymer.dom(this.$.someId) for style to apply?

Tags: javascript, polymer, material-design, shadow-dom

What's the difference in shadow dom performance between these two:

> - `Polymer.dom(this.$.someId)` or  `Polymer.dom(this.root)`
> - `this.$.someId` or `this.root`

---

Is there some type of digest or paint cycle that Polymer uses?

---

I was using `this.$.someId.appendChild` to append images from `Polymer.dom(this).querySelectorAll("img")` and everything looked great

Wasted an hour wondering why my style `#someId > img { display:none; }` wasn't working

Thanks

Comment: It's not clear to me what your question is about. In the title you ask why Polymer requires `Polymer.dom(this.$.someId)` and in the content you say "`this.$.someId.appendChild` and everything looked great". So, what did and what didn't work?

Comment: Hey cool, you're the same guy I asked about your host selector. Well, it looked great because the images were in the DOM, and visible, so I assumed that the append worked correctly. The problem was that my dom-module style tag couldn't select the `<img>` tags that I'd appended. Eventually, I got around to logging this.root and this.$.someId and realized they were actually document-fragments, not DOM nodes

Comment: I understand why it was confusing, didn't mention that I was passing in `<img>` elements to my `<carousel>` type component, querySelectoring them, and appending to local shadow dom

Comment: Looks like `this.$.someId` is the pure element while `Polymer.dom(this.$.someId)` returns it in a wrapper that uses the patched shady DOM API which is needed for shady DOM. This isn't necessary when shadow DOM (with full polyfills if not natively supported) is enabled.

Comment: I could definitely see that being the reason for wrapping it, still not sure why the unwrapped version couldn't be selected with my style tag in regular, shadow dom :/